# Is possible to restrict the Target branch browse option while merging in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I want to restrict the target branch selection browse option while merging the changes in TFS 2017 from freshers. Is there any possible way?

But in tfs 2010 Defaultly the browse option is not available in Target branch selection area. it available only in source branch.

If you select the source branch version the dropdownlist shows the list of branched target items for your source. We can select only from the dropdown.

But here they may change the target branch also.